# Execute command on shared account login

Tags: users, solaris, ksh, profile

At work our team uses a shared account "appadmin" to administer our application. At login, each one of us sources an "aliasrc" file containing his or her preferences. (aliases, display, prompt, ...).

So far I do something like this:

```
normaluser$ su - appadmin
password:
appadmin$ . ~normaluser/.aliasrc
[superprompt: appadmin@machine]$
```

I am looking to reduce all this to a single command. So far I have replaced the use of `su` by `rlogin` in order to take advantage of `.rhosts` and avoid having to input the password each time. (I know ssh is secure, but rlogin seems to be the standard around here).

Is there a way to source my aliasrc file as soon as I login in the shared account?

I don't insist on using `rlogin`. If you have something better to suggest I am all ears (... well eyes :-/ ).

Hope I am clear enough.

***Technical environment**: Solaris 10, Ksh.*

Answer (score 3):

You want to add something to `~appadmin/.profile` or another login script that will load `.aliasrc` based on who you were before switching users. The hard part is figuring out that username, since the usual methods aren't going to work:

```
$ whoami
appadmin

$ id
uid=1050(appadmin) gid=1050(appadmin)

$ id -ru
1050
```

I think the easiest way is to figure out which tty you're on (with the `tty` command), and check which user owns it -- that should be the user you connected as:

```
$ stat -c %U $(tty)
normaluser
```

Then you can just make sure ~normaluser/.aliasrc exists, and source it if so:

```
origuser=$(stat -c %U $(tty))
[ -e ~$origuser/.aliasrc ] && . ~$origuser/.aliasrc
```

Comment: You'll probably want to check whether it is readable with `-r` rather than if it merely exists.

Comment: It's not working :( The command `stat -c %U $(tty)` always returns "root".

Answer (score 2):

Okay.. I'm not familiar enough with `rlogin` or `ksh`, but this works with `bash` and `ssh`

1. create `touch .ssh/authorized_keys` file for appadmin and `chmod -R og-rwx .ssh`
2. for each user create public/priveta ssh keys with `ssh-keygen`
3. append your sshkeys public part (like `id_rsa.pub`) to appadmins authorized_keys
4. check that you can login with out password (passphrase is different and you should use it)
5. if login worked ok, add this to your line in authorized_keys before your key

   ```
   command="bash --rcfile /path/to/your/.profile" AAAA… rahmu@example.com
   ```
6. if everything worked ok, you should now have your session with your aliases. Also maintaining access to appadmin is relatively straightforward and as long as users use passphrase for ssh-keys it adds a bit more protection than palin old rlogin

[Howto configure/generate ssh-keys](http://kimmo.suominen.com/docs/ssh/)